# How to extract and use laser data from /scan topic in ROS using C++?

Tags: slam, navigation, scan, hokuyo-node, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

How do I subscribe to the /scan topic so that I can store laser scan data in a data structure? We are trying to get the data to use for control loops.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60239/how-to-extract-and-use-laser-data-from-/scan-topic-in-ros-using-c++?/) by [hesh8](https://answers.ros.org/users/4498/hesh8/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2013-04-08

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is an example:

```
ros::NodeHandle nh;
ros::Subscriber scanSub;

scanSub=nh.subscribe<sensor_msgs::LaserScan>("/scan",10,&AutoExp::processLaserScan,this);
```

You can implement the callback function however you like

```
void AutoExp::processLaserScan(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr& scan){
     //scan->ranges[] are laser readings
     ...
}
```

Whenever a new laser reading is published to the "/scan" topic, your callback function is called, assuming that nothing goes wrong.

You can always use commands like

```
rostopic info /scan
rosmsg show sensor_msgs/LaserScan
```

to have a detailed information about the topic and the message type.

If you read the documentation of the message type, it helps a lot. Here is the link  to [sensor_msgs/LaserScan Message](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/LaserScan.html)

---

Originally posted by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) with karma: 796 on 2013-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [umut](https://answers.ros.org/users/39446/umut/) on 2019-02-16**:
Sorry but I'm struggling with same problem and when I try to compile i recive error: ***‘AutoExp’ has not been declared***.
So which library should i include or which line(s) should i write to declare "AutoExp" ?

Heartfelt thanks.